How to write a code that executes after each login in ci4
I am using codeigniter 4 to build a web application. I want users to be mandated to update their profile on first login. They should not be able to proceed without updating their profile.
Please help me on how to point me to the right direction on what to use or how to achieve this.
I tried login event with shield, but the event does not execute if page is refreshed. I tried filters too, but I am not experienced using filters.
Thanks in advance for your kindness.
`Events::on('login', function (){
        $model = model('DashboardModel');
        $check_profile_setup = $model->check_profile_setup();
        
        if(!$check_profile_setup){
            exit(var_dump('stop here'));
        }else{
            exit('nothing');
        }`


This method will check if the user's profile is complete or needs updating. The logic can vary depending on how your profile information is structured in the database. Here’s a step-by-step guide:

Create or Edit DashboardModel

If you don't already have a DashboardModel, you can create one:
bash
php spark make:model DashboardModel

Or, if you already have it, locate and open the DashboardModel file in app/Models/DashboardModel.php.

Define the checkProfileSetup Method

The checkProfileSetup method should query the database to check whether the required profile fields are filled out. Here's an example implementation:
php >>
<?php namespace App\Models;

use CodeIgniter\Model;

class DashboardModel extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'users';  // Replace with your actual table name
    protected $primaryKey = 'id'; // Replace with your actual primary key

    public function checkProfileSetup($userId)
    {
        // Fetch the user record
        $user = $this->find($userId);

        // Assume 'profile_completed' is a boolean field in your users table
        // or you can check specific fields like email, phone, address, etc.
        if (!isset($user['profile_completed']) || !$user['profile_completed']) 

        {
            // Profile is not complete
            return false;
        }

        // Profile is complete
        return true;
    }
}

Explanation:

Replace 'users' with the actual name of your users' table.
Replace 'id' with the actual primary key field in your table.
The method checks if the profile_completed field (which you might
have in your database) is set and true. If not, it returns false,
indicating the profile is incomplete.

If you don't have a profile_completed field, you could check individual fields like this:
php >>
public function checkProfileSetup($userId)
{
        // Fetch the user record
        $user = $this->find($userId);

        // Check if essential fields are filled (replace with actual fields)
        if (empty($user['email']) || empty($user['phone']) || empty($user['address'])) {
        // Profile is not complete
        return false;
    }

    // Profile is complete
    return true;
}

In this version, the method checks if specific fields (like email, phone, and address) are filled. If any are empty, the profile is considered incomplete.
Summary
Modify your DashboardModel to include a method like checkProfileSetup.
Customize the method to reflect how you store profile completion status (using a specific boolean field or by checking key profile fields).
Integrate this method into the filter, as explained earlier, to enforce the profile update on the first login.
If you follow these steps, you'll be able to implement the necessary logic to ensure users complete their profiles on their first login. If you need more specific guidance based on your database schema, feel free to ask!

Thank so much. You have really helped me and thought me a lot.

This answer looks like it was copy-pasted from some AI tool

In CodeIgniter 4 (CI4), to mandate profile updates on the first login and ensure users cannot proceed without doing so, you need to integrate a mechanism that checks the user's profile status right after they log in. If the profile needs updating, you should redirect them to the profile update page. Here's how you can achieve this:
Using a Custom Filter
You can use a custom filter to ensure that users who need to update their profile are redirected to the profile update page. Filters are a good choice because they allow you to intercept requests and handle them accordingly.

Create a Custom Filter

Create a custom filter to check if the user's profile is set up. You can use the command line to generate the filter class:
php spark make:filter CheckProfileSetup

This will generate a filter class in app/Filters/CheckProfileSetup.php. Edit this file to include your logic:
<?php namespace App\Filters;

use CodeIgniter\HTTP\RequestInterface;
use CodeIgniter\HTTP\ResponseInterface;
use CodeIgniter\Filters\FilterInterface;
use App\Models\DashboardModel;

class CheckProfileSetup implements FilterInterface
{
    public function before(RequestInterface $request, $arguments = null)
    {
        $session = session();
        $userId = $session->get('user_id');

    if (!$userId) {
        // If no user is logged in, redirect to login page
        return redirect()->to('/login');
    }

    $model = new DashboardModel();
    $checkProfileSetup = $model->checkProfileSetup($userId);

    if (!$checkProfileSetup) {
        // Redirect to profile update page
        return redirect()->to('/update-profile');
    }
}

public function after(RequestInterface $request, ResponseInterface $response, $arguments = null)
{
    // Do something after the request
}

}
Adjust the checkProfileSetup method in your model to verify if the user's profile needs updating based on the user ID.

Register the Filter

Register your filter in app/Config/Filters.php:
public $globals = [
'before' => [
    // Other global filters
    'checkProfileSetup' => ['except' => ['login', 'register', 'update-profile']]
],
'after' => [
    // Other global filters
],

];
Here, except specifies that the filter should not be applied to the login, register, and update profile pages.

Redirect Users after Login

Ensure that the CheckProfileSetup filter is applied globally or to the routes where you want to enforce profile updates. Users will be redirected to the profile update page if their profile needs to be updated.

Model Method

Make sure the checkProfileSetup method in DashboardModel correctly checks if the user's profile needs updating:
public function checkProfileSetup($userId)
{
    // Your logic to check if the user's profile is set up
    // Return true if profile is set up, false otherwise
}

By setting up this filter and ensuring it's applied to the appropriate routes, you can enforce profile updates on first login and prevent users from accessing other parts of the application until their profile is updated.

I am not sure how to perform the number 3 point.
I really appreciate your response. Thanks

I changed
$userId = $session->get('user_id');
into
$userId = auth()->id(); to have it work. Note i am using shield

This method will check if the user's profile is complete or needs updating. The logic can vary depending on how your profile information is structured in the database. Here’s a step-by-step guide:

Create or Edit DashboardModel

If you don't already have a DashboardModel, you can create one:
php spark make:model DashboardModel

it's long, let me provide it in another answer!

Please I can go through it no matter how long it is. Please help me the more as you have been helping me already.
The repository is Project Repo
I added the database as ebank.sql in the project root folder
Thanks in advance
